# OCaml compilation speed & functors

Tags: compilation, ocaml, functor

Using functors in OCaml is essentially running code during compile-time (in that way I think they are closer to C++ templates then to Java generics).

Thus my question is: does the compiler perform any optimizations before compiling them, or does it start generating code straight away or does it try to perform any optimizations beforehand?

The question is more practical that it might seem. Quite often I use `Map.Make` or a similar functor to generate map/hashtable/etc for a given type. When I use it in multiple modules, I start to get worried, because I think that the compiler will start to do the same thing multiple times (and the compilation speed starts to become an issue for me, especially coming from the scripting language background).
So do I need to get worried? Or if I perform `Map.Make(MyModule)` in multiple modules would compiler be able to say "ohai I've just compiled this functor with this type I probably don't need to do it again?"

Yes I know that I can have a separate utils module and run all the functors in there, but I generally try to avoid utils-like-kitchen-sink modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> would compiler be able to say "ohai I've just compiled this functor with this type I probably don't need to do it again?"

You are thinking of the way templates are typically compiled by C++ compilers. The compilation scheme of `ocamlc` and `ocamlopt` instead produces generic code that does not need to be duplicated.

The OCaml functor `Map.Make` is compiled only once for all modules it may be applied to. The same code is executed when you call `iter` from `Map.Make(String)` and `iter` from `Map.Make(Float)`. Or indeed when you run `iter` from two different applications of `Map.Make` to `String`.

Comment: Oh okay, it looks like I misunderstood the module system altogether... But then I'm quite confused.
Floats and ints in OCaml are not boxed in OCaml, right? How can the same code be possibly run on two different unboxed types? Actually how is it even possible on boxed types with type erasure?

Comment: @cheshire OCaml floats **are** boxed. Only float arrays contain unboxed floats. OCaml ints are the same size as pointers and have their least significant bit set to distinguish them from pointers. Hence the two different `int` sizes making OCaml code less portable than, say, Java code, and the fact that these two sizes are 31-bit and 63-bit.

Comment: Thanks! I'm back to reading then... For some reason I thought that the beauty of OCaml is that it knows at compile time which function uses which type exactly and so could generate very fast code for unboxed values.

Comment: I'm also confused as to how OCaml can beat Java performance (in general) since in Java switching from `float` to `Float` causes a massive decrease in performance and OCaml is always using a boxed value.

Comment: @cheshire There is much in Java that is contrary to performance. But as someone who reads OCaml-generated assembly code for fun (a method I recommend if you want to see the generic code for yourself), there is also much unnecessary boxing/unboxing of floats that OCaml does and the compiler implementors are only starting on eliminating the most obvious ones. In any case, note that OCaml floats are boxed for a reason and that what Java gains by having unboxed floats lying on the stack, it has to pay with a more complex or conservative Garbage Collector, that may lose more in performance overall.